# How to write a PHP unit test for a method that uses live database data?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, php-7

How exactly do I write a test for a method that uses live database?

Consider this code:

```
class PricingRepository extends GenericRepository
{
    public function getOptionPrice(int $productId, int $quantity, float $productPrice = 0.0): float
    {
        //retrieves option record for a given product
        $row = $this->getMySql()->paramQuery("
            select * from pricing
            where product_id = ?", array(
            $productId
        ))->getSingleArray();

        //based on pricing type computes appropriate value
        if ($row['pricing_type'] === 'Quantity-based')
            return $row['base'] + $row['amount_per_quantity'] * $quantity;
        if ($row['pricing_type'] === 'Percentage-based')
            return $productPrice * $row['percentage'];

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("invalid pricing type detected");
    }
}
```

I have A LOT of methods like the one above, and so I want to ensure that my tests are solid and will not change when the database data changes.  I am looking for advice/solution towards best-in-class unit testing method and one that perhaps does not rely on changes of data in the database.

The way I could write a naive unit test now could be something like this:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
class OptionPricingTest extends TestCase
{    
    function setUp()
    {
        $this->pricingRepository = new PricingRepository();
    }

    function testOptionPricing()
    { 
        $actual_option_price = $this->pricingRepository->getOptionPrice(111, 1, 100);
        $this->assertEquals(10.0, $actual_option_price);
    }
}
```

But if the data or pricing type changes, my test will also have to change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The design of your repository makes it hard to test.

### Use Dependency Injection

Consider not to create the database connection within the repository class, but to inject it through the constructor instead.

```
interface DBInterface
{
    public function paramQuery($query, array $params = []): DBInterface;
    public function getSingleArray(): array;
    // ...
}

class GenericRepository
{
    /** @var DBInterface */
    private $mysql;

    public function __construct(DBInterface $mysql)
    {
        $this->mysql = $mysql;
    }

    protected function getMySql(): DBInterface
    {
        return $this->mysql;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then it gets easy to inject a mock object.

### Mock Dependency

For the testcase above, the mock could look like this:

```
class MysqlMock implements DBInterface
{
    private $resultSet = [];
    private $currentQuery;
    private $currentParams;

    public function paramQuery($query, array $params = []): DBInterface
    {
        $this->currentId = array_shift($params);
    }

    public function getSingleArray(): array
    {
        return $this->resultSet[$this->currentId];
    }

    public function setResultSet($array records)
    {
        $this->resultSet = $records;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way, you're independent from actual changes of prices and removal of products. You just have to change the test, if the *structure* of your data changes.

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
class OptionPricingTest extends TestCase
{    
    private $pricingRepository;
    private $mysqlMock;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->mysqlMock         = new MysqlMock;
        $this->pricingRepository = new PricingRepository($this->mysqlMock);
    }

    public function testOptionPricing()
    { 
        $this->mysqlMock->setResultSet([
            111 => [
                'pricing_type'        => 'Quantity-based',
                'base'                => 6,
                'amount_per_quantity' => 4,
            ]
        ]);

        $actual_option_price = $this->pricingRepository->getOptionPrice(111, 1, 100);
        $this->assertEquals(10.0, $actual_option_price);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a beginner at testing, so this answer might not be (very) useful or might even be wrong. If that is the case please correct me, so I can learn something from it :)

the first thing that comes to my mind would be inserting the entry to the `pricing` table with known parameters (store the id of the inserted row to `$insertedRowID`), then fetch use:

```
$actual_option_price = $this->pricingRepository->getOptionPrice($insertedRowID, 1, 100);
```

and then do the comparisson like you do now, but this way you are sure what the type and other relavant values are for the pricing. Repeat the same thing for all possible (known) scenarios, so that you verify all cases are working as expected. And also after the test removing the entry from the database (using the id stored when creating it).

The problem I see with this approach is, there is a chance that during the test (after the new row was added and before it is deleted), an exception might be thrown or some other error would happen, and that would result in a database entry that will not be removed. If that is the case, I guess a better approach would be to rewrite the code in such a way that allows you to use mocks or spies to "simulate" the database query method and always return the value that you would like to receive (and make as many tests as needed to cover all the variations that might come from the DB).

I'm not yet comfortable with using mocks and spies to the extent that I could explain them well, so hopefuly someone comes along with more experience and shines some light on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy it is possible to mock up a class without having to write your own mock class.

For example, if I start with this line in my test with the real database, where I use DI to inject `$mysql` into my repository class.

```
$this->pricingRepository = new PricingRepository($mysql);
```

I can instead mock `$mysql` like so, using `phpspec/prophecy`:

```
$sql = "
        select * from pricing
        where product_id = ?";
$data = [...]; // as returned by the database
$result = $this->prophesize(MySqlResult::class);
$mysql = $this->prophesize(MySql::class);
$mysql->paramQuery($sql, 111)->willReturn($result);

$this->pricingRepository = new PricingRepository($mysql->reveal());
```

Exact mock depends on the details of your `$mysql` class.  You essentially construct a mock of `$mysql` (including any supporting classes, such as `MySqlResult` in my case, telling it how to behave for your particular use case.  The mock framework does the rest.

What I am testing here is my `PricingRepository` class, which calls data, and does some computations on data.  I test those computations, while my mock provides data.  Effectively I am not testing the data or the database, I am testing specifically my `PricingRepository` class.  Should data change in the live database, it will not change my test.

Comment: You could also use PhpUnit's own MockBuilder, which is pretty sophisticated. But mocking frameworks tend to lead your attention to implementation details (in your example the query - the test relies on table names and a certain formatting). In your example, changing the fx. linebreaks in the SQL query would break the test, although the query actually would not change.

Writing your own mocks gives you much more control.

Comment: interesting, thanks! I like your `MysqlMock` implementation, and I see your point. Both ways have good sides, i.e. mock builders have standard API, while with your own mocks you have more control, but also more "work" writing classes that fit different molds.  For example, if SQL query relies on two parameters, such as `$productId` and `$productOption`, that will invalidate the `MysqlMock` and a different implementation will be required. i.e. `$this->currentId` will need to be reengineered to hold more key parameters, such as pairs `[111, 'X']`, `[111, 'Y']`, `[222, 'X']`, `[222, 'Y']`

Comment: That's correct. You taylor your mock to your exact needs. For other tests you might want to use a mock with more parameters. That, however, does not require this test and mock to be changed at all (if you need to change it, you most likely have a regression, which you usually want to avoid).

Comment: well if product_ids are different for each test run then I don't need to change the mock.  I have a case where I had the same product_id, but different product_option, which returned a different record, even when product_id was the same.  I hence needed a mock that was able to return a different result set for the same product_id.  The one above is not set up for it.  However, alternatively .. I could find a different set of data for the product_option I wanted to test, one with a different product_id, so I could reuse the mock as-is.

Comment: Ther _real_ id does not matter. The id only exists within a particular test.